# NSIS, download using default proxy

Tags: nsis

I want to download the .NET Framework using the default proxy configuration vom IE.
I did something like this with a static proxy configuration:

```
${If} $downloadMethod == "proxy"
inetc::get /CAPTION "Downloading .NET Framework..." /PROXY "$proxyHostURL:$proxyPort" /USERNAME "$proxyUsername" /PASSWORD "$proxyPassword" "${DOWNLOADURLDOTNET}" "${OUTPUTPATH}\${FILENAMEDOTNET}" /end
${EndIf}
```

Now i want an additional option where the command "inetc::get" using the IE proxy configuration automatically. Maybe like this:

```
${If} $downloadMethod == "defaultProxy"
inetc::get /CAPTION "Downloading .NET Framework..." /PROXY "!THEDEFAULTSEETINGS!" "${DOWNLOADURLDOTNET}" "${OUTPUTPATH}\${FILENAMEDOTNET}" /end
${EndIf}
```

I also tried the "NSISdl" command without any proxy declaration, but it didn't work :

```
NSISdl::download "${DOWNLOADURLDOTNET}" "${OUTPUTPATH}\${FILENAMEDOTNET}"
```

Comment: What is "not working"? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INetC uses the WinINet API and will use the system/IE proxy setting unless you specify something else with the /PROXY parameter or use /NOPROXY...